# How can I redirect my TensorFlow GPU utilization question to the right Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50777871/does-tensorflow-use-all-of-the-hardware-on-the-gpu) which has received multiple downvotes. The single, unsolicited comment on the questions is positive. The commenter suggested re-posting to [the AI Stack Exchange site](https://ai.stackexchange.com/tour). However, in the past, I have also received criticism for cross-posting. The commenter is perplexed about the downvotes, because the question seems appropriate. What should I do?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Performance questions often get downvoted, because of a single point:

## If you want to know the performance of something: measure!

Performance and utilization might be dependent on a lot of factors. Especially when proprietary software is involved, it might not be documented at all. And utilization is dependent on drivers, nVidia is known to optimize their drivers to increase performance. I'm not very familiar with CUDA, but I do know nVidia offers many [tools](https://developer.nvidia.com/performance-analysis-tools) to analyze it.

Because answerers can't measure component utilization for your setup, but you can, you probably should figure this out yourself.

Comment: I did measure.  I am looking at GPU-Z on a running neural net training session and I see various hardware functions are utilized.  Since I spent money to buy the GPU, I want to know how to improve it's utilizations.  If I know where the gap is (between Tensorflow and underlying CUDA) and whether it is material (how much silicon is wasted) I can, for example, remediate by making a clone of TensorFlow, modifying it, and then submitting a pull request.  In this matter though, because this is a significant effort, I seek community experience on the size of the gap.

Comment: Well, you might want to share such things in your question, and ask a more specific question. Your question shows no real research effort, but apparently, you've done quite a bit of research. If you show that, it might be received better (yes, some of the facts might not be immediately relevant, but people are more inclined to upvote and put work into their answer if they know you've put work into your question).

Comment: Thanks I will add above clarification into question.

Answer (score 6):

Hmm.

I hate to answer a question with a question, but... does it *really* matter?

It doesn't seem like you're programming a component using native CUDA that TensorFlow will then use, nor does it seem like the operation you describe specifies *which* part of the GPU is going to be used.

Why is this significant?  Are you noticing any slowdowns or performance hits *because* of this, and do you have comparable code which either does or does not use the streaming clusters with *different* performance?

---

That's kinda what I'm thinking right now about this question.  It's more of a passing curiosity than any demonstrable and actual *problem* you're having the library, so I'm unconvinced that it's on-topic anywhere, really.  It seems like it'd be a question you want to pose to the maintainers.

Comment: It matters in two ways: (1) Tensorflow uses CUDA.  CUDA has access, I presume, to all hardware components.  If Tensorflow can be improved by using those functions, the first thing to do is measure the gap.  (2) NVidia markets GPGPUs for neural net training.  So far it seems they have adopted a dual-use strategy for their circuits, so they are leaving in circuits not used for machine learning.  I know people at NVidia.  I can ask them if/when they will make a circuit that doesn't have unnecessary hardware.  I can also comparison shop with other manufacturers on this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nvprof (https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html) to profile your code. Use the --export-profile flag and visualize the generated .prof file using the NVIDIA Visual Profiler. After you have generated the visualization, you can see how much time is spent in various operations (Memcopy, computations, driver calls etc.). The visualization is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: I am using TensorFlow from Python on Windows 10.  I think I would need to rebuild the TensorFlow package from scratch to include nvprof.  Or is it possible to attach nvprof to a running process to get same info?  Does NVidia make the equivalent of GPU-Z app?

Comment: Hey. I'm not sure. Can you try and let us know? I did not have to rebuild tensorflow, I was able to attach it to the process.

Comment: One person tried it, failed, and asked the question (still unanswered): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42494479/nvprof-shows-error-with-tensorflow.  Some other related queries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42494479/nvprof-shows-error-with-tensorflow  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293714/can-i-measure-the-execution-time-of-individual-operations-with-tensorflow https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1824 https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/973490/visual-profiler/can-i-get-gpus-profile-of-tensorflows-mnist-by-nvidia-visual-profiler-/  I will try it and see.

Comment: It should take you only 5 minutes to do that, try it yourself and let me know. Don't profile the entire run, just profile it for a short time (say 10 iterations or something) and see if you're able to visualize it.