# What am I supposed to do about being pestered by a question asker who keeps changing the "intent" of the question?

Tags: discussion

Recently, I answered this question:

[Does TensorFlow use all of the hardware on the GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50777871/does-tensorflow-use-all-of-the-hardware-on-the-gpu/50801629?noredirect=1#comment88656071_50801629)

Which originally came about do to a severe lack of understanding of Nvidia's terminology for different levels of architecture abstraction, but where such knowledge was readily available in the paper that was linked.

I answered that question, only to find that the person who [asked did not understand why they were getting down-votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369291/how-can-i-redirect-my-tensorflow-gpu-utilization-question-to-the-right-stack-exc/369301#369301), and proceeded to go on meta, where they were met with individuals, who understandably, with out the background around CUDA and GPUs, thought the question was good.

After seeing my answer and seeing the recommendations there, they proceeded to change the [entire context of their question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50777871/revisions) to a completely different misunderstanding about a different set of terminology, which I also answered to the best of my ability, and also add some confusing fluff that seems to me to be irrelevant to the question they posed.

After answering that I was met with a flurry of confusing comments on my answer, one stating:

> I will probably check your answer but I still have to think about it. You are making some detailed remarks on CUDA using graphics-specific circuits when it can that tends towards "the exception proves the rule". I can easily imagine Google fabricating it's own chips for TensorFlow which are pure TensorFlow circuits with no strenuous optimization in the compiler to use odd circuits. **That's what this question is about, is there serious opportunity for TF-specific hardware or is NVidia's architecture within say 10% of optimal. (And what exactly is that %?)**

I didn't understand what the heck they were talking about the second sentence, but it appeared what they were trying to get answered was not the question they posed on their post. But the bolded part, if that was indeed their intended question, now seems entirely off topic.

Now this is frustrating me since they keep posting links of other non Nvidia devices made just for DNNs, I ultimately responded to the initial reply with:

> *"That's what this question is about, is there serious opportunity for TF-specific hardware or is NVidia's architecture within say 10% of optimal. (And what exactly is that %?)"* No, your question was originally about if TF utilized three different names for an abstraction on SM groupings, which you originally thought were separate, I answered that question. Then you asked about TF using TPCs and Texture units, which I also answered. This new question is actually entirely off topic and too broad for stack overflow... you need to quit changing your questions before this question gets nuked.

While not the nicest way to put things, I wanted them to know I was not happy with the behavior that was going on and for them to quit it. They then replied with:

> I guess you understand the intent of my question and I am trying to clarify the intent in good faith. I am asking the question for a reason and I am trying to clarify those reasons to be helpful. You are getting hot under the collar for no reason. StackOverflow is for people with sincere questions to get sincere answers. It is not a competition. I am being sincere. Please be sincere.

I don't want to get dragged into more spam over what ever they think their question is about, how do I get them to stop pestering me and stop changing their question? They've now appeared to push even more junk into their question, and even incorporated **my own answers** into their question as of now. This seems like an endless game back and forth and I want this to stop.

Comment: 1) 2 wrongs don't make a right... so even if the other user is changing his question, there is never any reason to be hostile.  2) the term you are looking for is "chameleon question". It appears on meta a bunch :). The answer to what to do with them? Walk away, or better: educate the OP and then walk away.

Comment: @Patrice maybe hostile was the wrong word, I was being crass, I feel it was necesary, and not a wrong.  And none of what you said addresses the spam they keep posting on my answer that I get in my inbox.

Comment: crass isn't really any better..... In any case, there is nothing to do but remove your content if you don't want to be pinged. There is no way to "silence" or block a user in these situations unfortunately (and I know I wasn't addressing your question, which is why I posted a comment, not an answer....)

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way to get someone to stop commenting on an answer is to delete it. I've had to do this a few times on Meta myself. The good news is that if you give it a few days you can try undeleting it after they've calmed down. This has always worked for me. I can't recall ever having to delete an answer twice. Also, it's been a few hours so maybe they won't reply again at all as long as you don't respond.

Comment: @BSMP Something I probably should have emphasized is the amount of positive reinforcement the user got is troubling to me.   The question originally was extremely (and still is) under-researched, but at least at the time was answerable.   Now a flurry of meta users have gone and up-voted the post due to I guess sympathy and a lack of understanding that they don't appear to understand *what* tensor flow does, what is required to program a neural network, what makes a neural network fast, and how Nvidia GPUs are architected... Now the question has gotten progressively worse...

Comment: You can delete all your comments if you feel those are addressed by you and then flag for a moderator to ask to nuke the remaining ones with as reason that the OP is asking a chameleon question / shows help vampire behavior which you're no longer interested in following up. That doesn't guarantee the comments will stop but at least it starts to build a flag record so you can more easily refer to previous behavior if you have to flag again.

Comment: Sometimes you need to know when to just walk away :)

Comment: @rene Ok, I think I just did what you said, I've at least deleted all my comments since they were useless at this point anyway, flagged the comment and explained the situation. Hopefully they won't continue this behavior but if they do It will be able for them to be brought to see what they were doing wrong.

Comment: I agree that question merits closure in its current state. It was probably well received at first from the interactions in another Meta question, or something else. It is known that some questions in deep learning related tags are not sufficiently moderated.